Equivalent Definitions for Group Central Series
The most common definition for $G=G_1\geq G_2 \geq \dotsc \geq G_n=\{1\}$ is a central series iff $[G,G_i]\subseteq G_{i+1}$ for every $i$. Note that this implies the series is subnormal.
In a textbook I’m reading, a group series (could be infinite, but let’s stick with finite in our case) is defined to be central iff for all $i,j, [G_i,G_{j}]\subseteq G_{i+j}$. I was hoping to see that these two definitions are equivalent by inducting on one of the indices but somehow I can’t get things to work. The textbook proves lower central series are central in the latter sense, but the proof relies on the fact that each $[G,G_i]=G_{i+1}$
I’m not entirely sure if these two definitions are equivalent. Any hint would be appreciated.

I'm not that strong in this part, but there's solvability and nilpotency.   The first generalizes the latter, I think.   Now the definitions are somewhat similar,  and I know John D. Dixon does it in Problems In Group Theory.  I seem to remember a couple ways of defining one or the other.   You or I can look into it.

@non-euclideangeometry This is nilpotence.

Note. I use the conventions that $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, and $[x,y,z]=[[x,y],z]$.
If $[G_i,G_j]\subseteq G_{i+j}$ holds for all $i$ and $j$, then we certainly have that $[G,G_i] = [G_1,G_i]\subseteq G_{i+1}$; so the second definition implies the first.
Conversely, assume that
$$ G= G_1\geq G_2\geq\cdots\geq G_n=\{1\}$$
is a series such that $[G,G_i]\subseteq G_{i+1}$. We want to show that it satisifes the second definition.
First let us note that the series is in fact a normal series; that is, $G_i\triangleleft G$ for all $i$. This follows because $[G,G_i]\leq G_i$, so for every $g\in G$ and $x\in G_i$, $g^{-1}xg = x[x,g]\in G_iG_{i+1}=G_i$.
Recall also the Three Subgroup Lemma:

Three Subgroup Lemma. Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be subgroups of $G$, and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If $[Y,Z,X]\leq N$ and $[Z,X,Y]\leq N$, then $[X,Y,Z]\leq N$.

We want to prove that $[G_i,G_j]\leq G_{i+j}$ for all $i$ and $j$ greater than or equal to $1$ (setting $G_k=\{1\}$ if $k\geq n$). The case $j=1$ is given. Assume that $[G_i,G_j]\leq G_{i+j}$ for all $i\geq 1$. Then
$$[G_i,G_{j+1}] = [G_{j+1},G_i]\leq [[G,G_j],G_i] = [G_1,G_j,G_i].$$
We now use the Three Subgroup Lemma: we know that $G_{i+j+1}$ is normal in $G$; set $X=G_1$, $Y=G_j$, and $Z=G_i$; we have that
$$[Y,Z,X] = [G_j,G_i,G_1] \leq [G_{i+j},G_1]\leq G_{i+j+1}$$ by the induction hypothesis and the assumption on the series; and that
$$[Z,X,Y] = [G_i,G_1,G_j] \leq [G_{i+1},G_j] \leq G_{i+1+j}$$
also by the induction hypothesis and the assumption on the series. Therefore,
$$[X,Y,Z] = [G_1,G_j,G_i]\leq G_{i+j+1},$$
which proves that $[G_i,G_{j+1}]\leq G_{i+j+1}$, as desired.
Thus, the series satisfies $[G_i,G_j]\leq G_{i+j}$ for all $i,j\geq 1$, proving the first definition implies the second.
